# React: Unable to set proxy server for react appllication

Tags: reactjs, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

I have my own react app and I tried adding proxy to the package.json, but it is not working.

On the other hand The simple create-react-app (as in the react basic example) works just fine but it does not have any webpack configured.

Here is my webpack:

```
const path = require('path')

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders:[
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                exclude: /node_modules/ 
            },
            { 
                test: /\.jsx$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                exclude: /node_modules/ 
            },
            { 
                test: /\.css$/, 
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader?modules" 
            },
            { 
                test: /\.png$/, 
                loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" 
            },
            { 
                test: /\.jpg$/, 
                loader: "file-loader" 
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
            },
            {     
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx' ,'.json'],
        modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules']
    },
    plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "A2ZPressMaterial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback",
    "webpack-watch": "webpack -w",
    "express-server": "node ./server",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run webpack-watch\" \"npm run express-server\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.19.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.2.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

I get 404 on my ajax/fetch calls.
My express sever is running on 3001.
The simple create-react-app is able to hit this server.
I run the react app as **yarn start** and express server as **npm start**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue here is that you're trying to use the `proxy` setting using your own webpack setup.

The `proxy` setting is a feature of `create-react-app` so if you're making your own setup you'll need to implement that manually.

Note that the documentation for the `proxy` setting is found in the `create-react-app` documentation, not the React documentation:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

---

Late answer in case anyone finds this question in the future.